# How to structure two different headers with ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm doing some refactoring with Angularjs 1.4.2 and ui-router and I'm not sure what the proper architecture should be for the change.

Currently, we are using $state.go("main"); to call a main route
and all subsequent routes, which are separate components with an html page, controller, and service for each.  I'm thinking that was used because only the main content was dynamic.

The header section is hard coded into the index.html page as I guess it was a quick fix.  The header content needed to be the same for all the pages.

What I'm attempting to do is break out the header html code from the index.html, into two different header pages that use the a new headerController and incorporate it with the existing app structure, unless that is the wrong architecture.  I have a simple plunker to try and get it working stand alone, 
but it's not doing anything when I click on the buttons.

So I have two questions, what is the proper ui-router structure for an app with two different headers and there may be one or two more added in later? 
I'm assuming I want to use two different states for this, rather than use url routing, but I can use either one.

The second question is: why doesn't my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MD4dZJsn6AUHCKTIZ588?p=preview) work?

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  document.write("In config!");
    $stateProvider
        .state('headerA', {
            url: "/headerA",
            templateUrl: "headerA.html",
            controller: "headerController"
        })
        .state('headerB', {
            url: "headerB",
            templateUrl: "headerB.html",
            controller: "headerController"
        })
});

myApp.controller('headerController', function($scope) {
  document.write("In config!");
   $scope.messageA = 'This is headerA!';
   $scope.messageB = 'This is headerB!';
})
```

headerA.html

```
<div>
  {{messageA}}
</div>
```

headerB.html

```
<div>
  {{messageB}}
</div>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@4.0.0-alpha.2" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.2/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.2" data-require="angular.js.1.3@*"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <!-- define angular controller -->
  <body ng-controller="headerController">
     <p></p>
    <div ui-view=""></div> 
     <p></p>
     <p></p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="headerA">headerA</a>
    <p></p>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" ui-sref="headerB">headerB</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: you need to name your ui-views in order to support nested states & multiple templates within a state.  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: as for why your Plunker is not working, I have no clue. I just tried to recreate that in a new plunkr and experienced the same issue.  I'm guessing it has to do with a combination of how the external scripts are loaded and the which versions are being used.

Comment: Well thanks for looking.  It was my first attempt at a ui-router plunker from scratch.  When I get time I'll try it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I ended up recreating this in Codepen.  For whatever reason, I couldn't get either Plunkr nor JSFiddle to work properly.*

## Multiple Named Views

UI Router allows you to set up multiple views in each state.  You simple need to:

#### 1) Name the view in your template

It's as easy as `<div ui-view="header">`

#### 2) Declare the named view within the state

```
$stateProvider.state( name, {
    views:{
         header: { ... }
         main: { ... }
    }
})
```

## Resources

- UI-Router Docs on Multiple Named Views - [docs](http://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)
- CodePen example (sorry I whipped this up in Jade/Coffeescript, easy enough to understand though) - [example](http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/ORNNAN)